# How to stop ignoring collisions in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a project in Unity 2D, and I needed a certain object to stop colliding with another, but only for a moment

I used this method to stop the collision, but I don't know how to get it back to normal

```
Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(6, 7);
```

Comment: i guess you didnt look at the usage - you're relying on a default parameter.. if you supplied it you can undo it..

Answer (score 1):

You can set whether you want to ignore the collision or not using the last parameter `ignore`.

```
public static void IgnoreLayerCollision(int layer1, int layer2, bool ignore);
```

> Choose whether to detect or ignore collisions between a specified pair of layers.

When you want to ignore, pass true:

```
Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(6, 7, true);
```

And when you no longer want to ignore, set ignore to false:

```
Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(6, 7, false);
```

[Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision.html)

Comment: it was so simple lol
thank you very much

Comment: @Pbwanska if this helped you to fix it or even solved your problem, then please, mark this as an Accepted Answer.